# Multiple lines in AWS Cloudwatch Dashboard graph

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I've created a query which shows me all requests made by my backend by querying Cloudwatch logs.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
    | filter strcontains(@message, "[RequestStart]: Sending HTTP request")
    | stats count(*) as requestCount by bin(1h)
    | sort requestCount desc
```

This creates a graph like this in my dashboard:
[image]

My goal is to filter the logs by multiple strings and each of this filter I want as a line in the graph, for instance by HTTP method. In this case I would filter by text "[RequestStart]: Sending HTTP request GET".

So as the end result, I want to have multiple lines each representing different filter, so I can see correlations.